Create an Object From Raw Pointer and Metadata
I am trying to do something complex in rust with wasm_bindgen I cannot export generic structs/functions from rust to javascript.
What I'm trying to do is something like this.
some function
pub fn foo() -> (String, *const ()) {
    let a: RandomType = //Create object
    (a.get_metadata(), a.get_ptr())
}

This function will be exported to JS and here the String will be the metadata.
another function
pub fn goo(metadata: String, ptr: *const ()) -> SomeType {
    let a = //do something with metadata and ptr to get object
    let b: SomeType = a.into();
}

of course, I will implement the Into Trait for whatever type a is supposed to be.
Basically, this type cannot be known at compile time. Is there a way to achieve this?
The Highlighted post talks about one function having 2 different return types and that is not what this is about at all. The return of function goo never changes. I just need a way to read data from a raw pointer.

If the type never changes, why does you need a metadata?

because one function is exporting a pointer to javascript. That pointer itself could be of a few different types of objects but the return type of function goo does not change

@VipulRajan the thing you have to add instead of //do something with metadata and ptr to get object is the bit that requires a conditional type of some expression, you can do so as specified in the linked question. I.e. the type of a does change, but it can't, you can use an enum to still store the different types.

Then the solution is exactly as in the duplicate: return an enum (or a pointer to an enum).

The pointer can only be a raw pointer. Even if it points to an enum, how does one reconstruct the object?

It's trivial to reconstruct an object from a pointer if you know it's always of the same type (the enum type). Or you construct a new enum from the pointer and get the variant to construct from the metadata.
